# How to Join 2 Tables Into Another Table

Tags: mysql

Here's my table list:

```
tblsection
tblgradelevel
tblteachers
```

My `tblsection` contains:

```
Section_ID | GradeID | sectionname | TeacherID
```

My question is how can I link `GradeID` and `TeacherID` in `tblsection`.

My foreign keys in `tblsection` are:

```
Foreign key name   | Reference table            |  Column  | Reference Column
Section_GradeID    | 'database','tblgradelevel' | GradeID  |     GradeID
Section_TeacherID  |'database','tblteacher'     | TeacherID|   Teacher_ID
```

I use many queries to perform this problem but it does not work.

Here's my query:

```
"SELECT 
       a.Section_ID AS ID, 
       a.Sectionname AS SName,
       b.GradeLevel AS Level,
       c.TeacherID as Teach 
 FROM tblsection 
 INNER JOIN tblGradelevel b ON a.GradeID = b.GradeID";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
**The query will generate errors due to invalid alias for the table name tblsection **
Try below query:
SELECT 
   a.Section_ID AS ID, 
   a.Sectionname AS SName,
   b.GradeLevel AS Level,
   c.TeacherID as Teach 
FROM tblsection a
INNER JOIN tblGradelevel b ON a.GradeID = b.GradeID
INNER JOIN tblteachers c   ON a.TeacherID = c.TeacherID
```

Comment: im wondering if a.Section_ID AS ID, and for the next is a AGAIN?

Comment: Yes because you forgot to add alias name for tblsection as a, so the a.Section_ID will cause error.

Comment: hi theres an error "you hyave an error using your syntax near c. TeacherID as Teach as Teach from tblsection a INNER JOIN  tblgradelevel b. on a.GradeID =  at line1"

Answer (score 0):

`$sql="select a.Section_ID, a.Sectionname, b.GradeLevel, c.TeacherID from tblsection a INNER JOIN tblgradelevel b ON a.GradeID=b.GradeID INNER JOIN tblteachers c On a.GradeID=c.TeacherID";`

the two values must be same ex: `a.gradeID=b.gradeId` then only the query will execute. 
 I'm not check this one, but i'm using this way to my application.

Comment: hi my problem is iwant to link a gradelevel and teacherid into section form example all details in grade level will sync automatically same as in teacherid icant link teacherid only the gradelevel will function